# Rsync won't sync recursively two directories in 2 different NTFS partitions

Tags: linux-mint, rsync, ntfs, recursive

I am using Linux Mint 17, arch x64. When trying to sync two directories from 2 different locally mounted NTFS partitions, it won't recurse, but instead copy only the files found in the 1st level directory.

It works fine on 2 ext4 partitions.

Command: `rsync -rtv /path1 /path2`

rsync version: 3.1.0

Comment: Maybe it thinks it's already done the work. This will copy everything under `/path1` and place it underneath `/path2/path1`. But without additional information there's nothing for us to go on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say

Comment: I'm asking you to confirm that hasn't already dune what I've just described, and if indeed it hasn't then to provide more information for someone to try and diagnose the problem. As it stands there isn't any information to go on.

Comment: I know. That's the most details I could give. As I said, it will copy only all files (except dirs) found on the 1st level dir and won't continue the recursion. I asked maybe someone else had same problem, or is a known bug for NTFS partitions or something. Also `rsync /path1 /path2` without recursion, has the same problem, i.e. doesn't copy dirs. Idk how to be more clear than this.

Comment: Let's assume you're using `rsync -rvt /a/b/c/dir1 /x/y/z/dir2`. Please look in `/x/y/z/dir2/dir1` and confirm that your files and directories from `dir1` aren't hidden away in there where you might not have expected them.

Comment: I got what you mean, the answer is still the same, it doesn't do the recursive part, nor copy other dirs found inside /a/b/c/dir1